# Nothing happen when execute Maven launch4j .exe

Tags: java, netbeans, maven-plugin

launch4j to an exe file. Here is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
    <artifactId>InsertMySQL</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.45</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>com.mycompany.insertmysql.insert</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.akathist.maven.plugins.launch4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>launch4j-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>l4j-gui</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>launch4j</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <headerType>gui</headerType>
                            <outfile>target/Project.exe</outfile>
                            <jar>target/InsertMySQL-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar</jar>
                            <!-- if <dontWrapJar>true</dontWrapJar> change to this conf <jar>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}.jar</jar> -->
                            <dontWrapJar>false</dontWrapJar>
                            <errTitle>Error in launch4j plugin</errTitle>
                            <classPath>
                                <mainClass>com.mycompany.insertmysql.insert</mainClass>
                            </classPath>

                            <jre>
                                <minVersion>1.7.0</minVersion>
                                <maxVersion>1.9.0</maxVersion>
                                <initialHeapSize>512</initialHeapSize>
                                <maxHeapSize>1024</maxHeapSize>
                            </jre>
                            <versionInfo>
                                <fileVersion>1.0.0.0</fileVersion>
                                <txtFileVersion>1.0.0.0</txtFileVersion>
                                <fileDescription>des</fileDescription>
                                <copyright>Copyright (c) 2014 </copyright>
                                <companyName>comp</companyName>
                                <productVersion>3.0.0.0</productVersion>
                                <txtProductVersion>${project.version}</txtProductVersion>
                                <productName>Project</productName>
                                <internalName>Project</internalName>
                                <originalFilename>Project.exe</originalFilename>
                            </versionInfo>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

above is my  POM.xml

**Question**
when double click on project.exe , nothing is executed.nothing is appear.nothing happen after execute the project.exe
anything wrong at this code??
what i have missed? still need to install anything or what? is yes, please step by step guide me, thx =)

[image]

**UPDATE**
after i had run the cmd `java -cp C:\Users\chiny\Desktop\InsertMySQL\target\InsertMySQL-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.insertmysql.insert` to solve `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver`

so, i had searched the solution, just mention to add the dependency, as you can see, my pom.xml is attached with dependency mysql connector already. i have no idea how to solve it

**UPDATE 2**

[image]

how about i get this error? what is this?

**ALL THE PROBLEM IS the CLASSPATH, java can't find the mysql-connector-java.jar path. how to solve it?**

but when i m runing with `java -cp .;C:\Users\chiny\.m2\repository\mysql\mysql-connector-java\5.1.45\mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar;C:\Users\chiny\Desktop\InsertMySQL\target\InsertMySQL-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.mycompany.insertmysql.insert` with `mysql-connector-java-5.1.45.jar` then the project.exe able to run..how to set the nysql connector classpath in programmatically ?

Comment: Try to run the exe from a terminal. Any error might show up there.

Comment: You can execute the `Project.exe` by using java from a terminal: 
`java -jar Project.exe`. Try this maybe there is an error in console showing up.

Comment: @JensV `Error: Unable to access jarfile Project.exe` this error

Comment: @GeorgHenkel - It is an exe file.  That's not how you run an exe file!!

Comment: @StephenC you can, I do it with my installers created with Launch4j all the time, when they are not working as expected to get better logging.

Comment: @JohnWalker Try to run it without `java -jar`

Comment: @GeorgHenkel `no main manifest attribute` i get this error

Comment: @GeorgHenkel Updated with error

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a shade jar file to include all needed dependencies, but in the configuration of the launch4j plugin you are referencing the unshaded jar file. Update the plugin configuration to use the correct jar:

```
<jar>target/InsertMySQL-1.0-SNAPSHOT-shaded.jar</jar>
```

Comment: error with `com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure`

Comment: Seems you are doing some logic in the main class of your jar. Make sure that communication to the MySQL server is possible. This exception has nothing todo with te problem you are facing in your question. Do you get this exception, if you run your code from your IDE?

Comment: Maybe this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6865538/solving-a-communications-link-failure-with-jdbc-and-mysql

Comment: Did you change your pom to the mentioned (shaded) jar in the launch4j configuration? So then please update the code of the pom.xml in your question.

Comment: I had solved my problem with copy the MySQL-connector-java.jar and paste it at the project.exe same directory. How to specific the jar path in somewhere?